# Avoid showing selected text in Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-xml

The default behavior of the android spinner is to initially display the first item in the top of the dropdown portion of the spinner. As the user selects other items/text in the dropdown, it will update the text at the top with the selected item.

I don't want any text to show up at all in the top part of the spinner. **Without having an empty sting as the first item**, because that leaves a gap. Does anyone know how to do that? This is what I have so far

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.PopupMenu" name="SpinnerAsEditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/filter_arrow</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

this is my layout: main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/list"
        style="@style/SpinnerAsEditText"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is a visual representation of my problem -  if you click on this image/gif, it should animate my problem.

[image]

Comment: Add one empty item and set it not to respond on click.

Comment: @fox Thanks for the quick response...i dont want to do that because having an empty string leaves an uneccessary gap in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use popUpWindow to show dropDownList.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="+@id/spinnerImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showSpinner" />
```

in java

```
findViewById(R.id.spinnerImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             mSortPopupWindow = popupWindow(spinnerItemList);
                    mSortPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, -5, 0); // This is impotent to where to show drop down   
            }
        });

 public PopupWindow popupWindow(String[] stringArray) {
        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(mContext);
        ListView listView = new ListView(mContext);

        listView.setAdapter(dropDownAdapter(stringArray));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener( AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Selected" + stringArray[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }

    });

        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setWidth(250);//Or you can set wrap_content
        popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindow.setContentView(listView);

        return popupWindow;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is the most practical answer so far...I will try a few more things and resort to the popup window as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/list"
        style="@style/SpinnerAsEditText"/>
 </RelativeLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <resources>  
     <array name="list">  
    <item></item>  
    <item>second</item>  
    <item>third</item>  
    <item>fourth</item>  
    <item>fifth</item>  
     </array>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however i dont want to have an empty item because that leaves an uneccessary gap in the dropdown.

Comment: Also this doesnt solve my problem, if you select an item in the dropdown, it will still show the text at the top

Comment: You can have a simple solution then take a textview set spinner image as background and click of textview you can open a dialog with list.you can do what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an image which when clicked on shows the spinner.  Initially the spinner would be hidden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="+@id/spinnerImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showSpinner" />
<Spinner
    android:id="+@id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/list"
    style="@style/SpinnerAsEditText"
    android:visibility="hidden"/>
```

and in Java:

```
void showSpinner() {
   findViewById(R.id.spinnerImage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
   findViewById(R.id.spinner).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```